# Heroku SSL Cloudfront Missing Key-Pair-Id 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to serve all assets through cloudfront on my Rails 4.2 app hosting on Heroku.  I have been successful using cloudfront before using heroku apps that have somename.herokuapp.com,  but this one has a custom domain and a wildcard SSL. I cannot get any of the assets to serve, they all have 403

I have tried uploading my SSL on AWS & also tried using the Default CloudFront Certificate (*.cloudfront.net) (which works for my non-custom domain apps).

I have made sure my SSL is in the region on AWS that AWS wants it to be (N.Virginia).

I have made sure I'm only using HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0.

I have made sure my distribution is 'enabled'.

My SSL is a wildcard so it looks like this '*.mydomain.com'

When I uploaded it to AWS and added it to  my distribution, I see that it is in use.

I have made sure that my aws_id/aws_key are valid.  However, there is some sort of Cloudfront key/pair, but I don't know where I would put that on my site, I only have ENV variables for aws_id/aws_secret_key.

```
Request URL:https://mycloudfrontdistn.cloudfront.net/assets/subfolder/secondfolder/gift-52db27eb2ced10800db38fbd74ec2ef40704d8c55d49b2654f7fe014e4bd1eff.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:REDACTED (I don't know if this is sensitive)
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:146
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Fri, 04 Nov 2016 23:06:47 GMT
Server:CloudFront
Via:1.1 somebignumber.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:myAmazonKey==
X-Cache:Error from cloudfront

Request Headers
view source
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:mycloudfrontdist.cloudfront.net
Referer:https: https//www.mysite.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you enable [Restrict Viewer Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesRestrictViewerAccess) on the cache behavior on the distribution, but you are not actually using CloudFront signed URLs because the content is public.

> If you want requests for objects that match the PathPattern for this cache behavior to use public URLs, choose No.

Comment: What if I have both public & private user content

Comment: You have to segregate the content under different paths, and create a cache behavior matching each path, with the appropriate setting for Restrict Viewer Access for each -- e.g. you might have an `/asset/*` behavior with the property set to No and a `/private/*` pattern with the property set to Yes -- **or** your application will need to sign *all* CloudFront URLs in your app.  See [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) for how the authorization information is commonly presented to CloudFront.